# Why does int seem to default to 50 rather than 0 in C#?

Tags: c#

My goal here is to ask the user to which of the three pre-determined ascii art picture they would like to print and how many times they would like to print it. My problem is that it print about 50 times more than whichever number was chosen. I tried converting the print variable, but that didn't work. I'm fairly new to C# so I apologize for any major, basic errors.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Would you like to print picture 1, 2, or 3?");

        int print = 0;
        string choice = "";


        while (choice != "end")
        {
            choice = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (choice)
            {
                case "1":
                    Console.WriteLine("How many times would you like to print it");
                    print = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    while (print > 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(cocaCola);
                        print -= 1;
                    }
                    break;
                case "2":
                    Console.WriteLine("How many times would you like to print it");
                    print = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    while (print > 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(beam);
                        print -= 1;
                    }
                    break;
                case "3":
                    Console.WriteLine("How many times would you like to print it");
                    print = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    while (print > 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(liberty);
                        print -= 1;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You chose nothing");

                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Choose again, or type \"end\" to exit");
```

Comment: check the docs of `Console.Read()`. It does not do and return what you expect.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not printing 50 more times; it's printing exactly 48 more times.

You're reading a character and assigning its unicode value to an integer. For example, user types '1', the character `1`. Its Unicode value is 49. You assign 49 to your int `print`, and there you are. A character is really a small or smallish integer, which is essentially an index into a table of characters somewhere.

In Unicode, as in ASCII, '0' is decimal 48, '1' is decimal 49, and so on in order up to '9'. That's where the 48 is coming from.

What you want to do is something more like this. First, you want to read the whole line, not just the first character; what if the user types "12"? Then you need parse the string "1" (or "12", which is two characters) to get the integer '1' or '12'.

And in fact, that's just what you did on this line:

```
print = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

So use that version every place that you've got `print = Console.Read();`

Second bug: You set print to some presumably small number, say the user types "4" so it's `4`. Then you loop while it's *greater than* 10 -- but it's never greater than 10. You want to loop while it's greater than zero:

```
while (print > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cocaCola);
    print -= 1;
}
```

You need to fix that in three places.

### Update

Three places is more than you want to deal with. So here's another thing: You could simplify this code quite a bit by just setting a variable in the switch statement, and writing the loop only once (you could simplify it further in other ways, but let's take one step at a time):

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to print picture 1, 2, or 3?");

int print = 0;
string choice = "";


while (choice != "end")
{
    choice = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
    String thingToPrint = null;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case "1":
            thingToPrint = cocaCola;
            break;

        case "2":
            thingToPrint = beam;
            break;

        case "3":
            thingToPrint = liberty;
            break;
    }

    if (thingToPrint != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many times would you like to print it");
        print = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        while (print > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(thingToPrint);
            print -= 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You chose poorly. Try again.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Choose again, or type \"end\" to exit");
}
```

Comment: The weird thing is that the OP does have that before the switch.

Comment: @juharr Yes. But it's so easy to get mixed up when you're first learning. Half the stuff you write is a guess. It's a mystery to me what he's getting zapped for.

Comment: When I did what you suggested, it stopped printing out the ascii art. It simply keeps asking the questions without printing it out

Comment: @DevinRogers Whoops, my bad -- you need to loop while print is > 0, not while print > 10

Comment: @EdPlunkett That was it. Thank you for the help, I'll make sure I learn a lot more about debugging

Comment: @DevinRogers Excellent. You could definitely have saved yourself some trouble by setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code, once you had the `print` thing squared away. By the way, see final update.